# How can we override the Print Shipment Confirmation report name in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

I used `PXOverride` to override the action and added `adapter.Menu = "PickSlip"` to change the `Action` name.
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: On which form you've added it?

Comment: We have added in the Shipment Screen

Answer (score 0):

The text is defined in a localized constant - PX.Objects.SO.SOShipmentEntryActionsAttribute.Messages.PrintShipmentConfirmation. I was unable to override using Automation Steps, but was able to change it in the Translations since it has a PXLocalizable attribute.

I went to form SM200540 and searched for Print Shipment Confirmation and entered the English translation as Pick Slip and it updated on the menu.

Comment: We are able to change the menu name but if we click on the Quick Process action 
we are unable to redirect to the report instead we are facing with the below issue

Comment: Do you have custom code to add the Printing of the shipment confirmation added 
 to the Sales Order screen? Does the new text work from the Shipments screen?

Comment: It worked in the shipment screen for changing the menu but from sales order screen if we run the Quick Process by checking the Pick Slip check box we are facing with the above mentioned issue

Comment: What version of Acumatica are you using? I was able to change the language as stated using 19.200.0081. I then went to order types and checked the box for SO for Pick Slips. It then redirected to that screen when stating to open all screens in a new window. Maybe go back to the Order Types screen and verify the checkbox appears with the proper name, uncheck it and save, and re-check it?